# How Deadlock Happen resolved on Same Table insertion and update

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a SSIS package with a task to load data. For some reason i need to update and insert same destination table. This happen deadlock

I use SSIS MULTI-CAST control.

[image]
What to do? how to resolve this situation?

Comment: Don't do both steps at the same time?

Comment: @ Sean Lange, after insert how to update same record set? Is  ISOLATION LEVELS IN SSIS help to resolve this situation.

Comment: If you need to insert data and then immediately update it you should wait until the insert finishes before you try to update it. Or even better, figure out the correct values before you insert them but this isn't always possible.

Comment: write the insert statement in the OLE DB COMMAND and after you write the update statement

Answer (score 0):

In your OLE DB Destination, change the access mode from "FastLoad" to "Table or View". The former will take a table lock which is generally better for large inserts but in your scenario, you need the table to remain "unlocked." Your performance will suffer since you'll be issuing singleton inserts but I guess that doesn't really matter since you'll also be doing singleton updates with your "OLE DB Command"

Finally, I think you're doing this wrong. The multicast essentially duplicates a row so that you can direct it to N components. I generally see people trying to detect whether a row exists in the target and then either insert or update it based on that lookup. But that's the lookup component, not a multicast. Maybe you're doing a type 2 dimension or something but even then, there will be better ways to accomplish this versus what you're showing in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Your way seems strange, as **billinkc** said, you are effectively double data rows and perform INSERT and UPDATE actions with the same table concurrently from two different connections/contexts. This have to end in a deadlock.

I would use alternative approach - do required transforms with the data, and then write it to an intermediate table in the DataFlow. Then on the next SSIS task - execute [MS SQL MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) - Microsoft table upsert - with OLE DB Command. This will assure you do not have a deadlock between concurrent operations, logic of the MERGE could be quite flexible.

Last but not the least - use dedicated or global *##temp* table for an intermediate table, Working with regular MS SQL *#temp* tables in SSIS is little tricky. Do not forget to clean up intermediate before and after MERGE, or create and dispose of ##temp table properly.